# how to mute Audio/video in website onload for any tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i want to mute audio and video sound in my website. the will not be any particular id or class name. it will very that i don't know what the id name can be. so i would like to track via video/object/div/src html tag name and mute the sound.

is this possible by javascript? i have tried the following code; but it does not work. i appreciate your best suggestion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="enableMute()" type="button">Mute sound</button>


<video width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
} 


</script> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: will you have only one video source ?

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of objects. So if you want to mute them all simply loop through them all and mute them:

```
document.onload = function() {
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        videos[i].muted = true;
    }

    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

    for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
        audios[i].muted = true;
    }
}
```

Since you tagged the question as jQuery, here is the jQuery variant:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('video, audio').prop('muted', true);
});
```

**Update - How to mute iframes**

To mute iframes, it's a bit different. In the same idea, you loop through them but they do not have a `mute` property.

In JavaScript:

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"setVolume", "value":0}', '*');
}
```

jQuery variant:

```
$('iFrame').each(function() {
    this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"setVolume", "value":0}', '*');
});
```

[JavaScript demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/qg775xey/)

[jQuery demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/hx44f85j/)

Comment: if it is another tag name like iframe or object, will i make same code ?

Comment: @ZahirulHaque No, the code would be different for an iFrame or object or embed.

Comment: @ZahirulHaque Although, the last two are deprecated, so you shouldn't use them. Give me a minutes to update my answer with how to mute iframes.

Comment: Hi, I am loading whole pages of various video page of websites by cURL in php, So this is not working for all the case. Most importantly when the video page is from youtube.com or dailymotion.com

Comment: @ZahirulHaque Could you replicate your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @ZahirulHaque Thanks for your php code. Could you show me an example of what would contain your variable `$result`? Perhaps you could write it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? I need to know what your iframes look like.

Comment: $result actually load all the content of the given url. so, it is not sure about video tag, it maybe iframe or video or object what ever the url page use. if you know cURL you can understand the result. I have give the whole code there. you can simply run the code in a php file and see the result if  you like

Comment: I see.. it seems like your video is an embed object. You can see it by running your page and analyzing your page with your browser tools. It is a lot more complicated to mute an embed object. I tried adding an attribute volume with 0 as value, but it wouldn't add it. So unfortunately, I can not help you on this one. As far as the question is concerned, you were only asking about videos and audios. I suggest you ask another question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do using Javascript with jQuery. This method will mute **all** video elements on the page.

```js
var sound = true;

function muter() {
    if (sound === true) {
        $("video").prop('muted', true);
        sound = false;
        $('button').text('Sound');
    } else {
        $("video").prop('muted', false);
        sound = true;
        $('button').text('Mute');
    }
}

$('button').click(function(){
    muter();
});
```

```css
button{
    width:50px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Mute</button>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```